# Automotive Load-dumps, ISO standards & Meaning behind datasheet

Tags: automotive, circuit-protection, over-voltage-protection, transient-suppression

Im looking towards using an system basis IC for one of my designs (UJA1164A)
and i noticed that under the features & benefits it notes that

> "Battery and CAN bus pins protected against automotive transients
> according to ISO 7637-3"

i unfortunately don't have access to the sheet so i'm unaware to how far this standard goes, and wanted a second opinion.
In either a 12v or 24v automotive application how well would it fare (or at all) with a load dump, especially if we're talking about a 24v system that expects around 170v for few hundred ms without a beefy TVS to clamp it ?

[image: diagram]

worst case i was looking to the TIDA-00992 for additional protection or putting in some big boy tvs suggested on here [Link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/8798/how-do-i-protect-against-an-automotive-load-dump)

or one of these tvs [tvs link](https://au.mouser.com/datasheet/2/240/Littelfuse_TVS_Diode_SLD8S_Datasheet.pdf-1022642.pdf)

Comment: From memory, ISO7637-3 is for Signal Lines only, and contains only short sharp low(ish) energy transients. ISO7637-2 is for supply lines, and has Load Dump. For 24V system you'll most likely need a Transzorb, as you say. Do lots of testing, including in-vehicle. Truck power supply is really nasty.

Comment: http://www.compel.ru/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/ISO-7637-22011E.pdf - part 2 and [useful info about part 3](https://biblio.ugent.be/publication/8548379/file/8548382)

Comment: @Andyaka you're a legend !

Comment: @elchambro haha, sorry for the terminology it's a TVS series name. Yeah definitely will do alot of testing, i've read that its an absolute arse to work with.